# tslearn time series clustering ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 2 entries

Tags: python, time-series, k-means

I am trying to do a kmeans clustering for time series data using tslearn. I am doing the clustering 110 times for 110 different files. Sample data for 1 particular file is attached below, after doing `x = np.squeeze(to_time_series_dataset(x))` to the original data x. I also tried to use the data without squeezing it, but the value error `ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 2 entries` pops up still for certain videos.

From my understanding, I suspect maybe because in some files, there is only 1 value that is not `nan`, such as cases like `[1, nan, nan, nan]`. If so, I cannot really replace `nans` with actual values because in my data, -1 represents "no", 0 represents "not sure", and 1 represents "yes". That's also why I don't normalize the data since it's already on the scale of -1 to 1.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
[[ 0.  1. -1. nan]
 [-1.  1.  0. -1.]
 [ 0. -1. nan nan]
 [ 0.  0. -1. nan]
 [ 0.  1.  0. -1.]
 [ 0. -1. nan nan]
 [ 0. -1. -1. nan]
 [ 0.  0. -1. nan]
 [ 0. -1. nan nan]
 [ 0. -1. nan nan]
 [ 0.  0. -1. nan]
 [-1. -1. nan nan]
 [ 1.  1. -1. nan]
 [ 1. -1. nan nan]
 [ 0. -1. nan nan]
 [ 1. -1. nan nan]
 [ 0. -1. -1. nan]
 [ 0. -1. nan nan]
 [ 1. -1. nan nan]
 [ 0.  0. -1. nan]
 [ 0. -1. -1. nan]
 [ 0.  1. -1. nan]
 [ 0.  0. -1. nan]
 [ 1. -1. nan nan]]
```

If I didn't squeeze the data, it would be like this

```
[[[ 0.]
  [ 1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[-1.]
  [ 1.]
  [ 0.]
  [-1.]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [ 1.]
  [ 0.]
  [-1.]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[-1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 1.]
  [ 1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [ 1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 0.]
  [ 0.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]]

 [[ 1.]
  [-1.]
  [nan]
  [nan]]]
```

I call the following to do the actual clustering. Since I'm not sure how many clusters are the best for each file, I try 2, 3, or 4 clusters and evaluate their silhouette scores.

```
for j in [2,3,4]:
    km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=j, metric="dtw")
    labels = km.fit_predict(x)
    silhouetteScore = silhouette_score(x, labels, metric="dtw")

    num_of_clusters_list.append(j)
    silhouetteScore_list.append(silhouetteScore)
    print(f"{j} clusters, score is {silhouetteScore}")
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score -2):

You can find optimal K using the KneeLocator (or ElbowLocator).